# How can I add Share Button to my android app

Tags: android

How can I add Share Button to my android app, I tried several solutions here in and nothing seems to work.

**Activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.package.name.MainActivity"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toll_bar"
        />

    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="495dp"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp">
        tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
            android:layout_width="383dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            />
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Toll_bar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textColorHighlight="#000000"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/about"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:text="About"
        android:background="@drawable/icon"
        android:layout_marginLeft="127dp"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/share"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:text="share"
        android:background="@drawable/share"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/rate"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:text="Rate Us"
        android:background="@drawable/rate"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**Main_Activity.xml**

```
package com.package.name;

import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Toolbar toolbar;



    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://beta.html5test.com/");
        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/Html36289/index.html");
        // Force links and redirects to open in the WebView instead of in a browser
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        // Stop local links and redirects from opening in browser instead of WebView
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient());

        mWebView .getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        Button btnRate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rate);
        btnRate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onClickRateThisApp(v);
            }});
    }

    private boolean isActivityStarted(Intent aIntent) {
        try
        {
            startActivity(aIntent);
            return true;
        }
        catch (ActivityNotFoundException e)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void onClickRateThisApp(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.supercell.hayday"));
        if (!isActivityStarted(intent)) {
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.package.name"));
            if (!isActivityStarted(intent)) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Could not open Android market, please check if the market app installed or not. Try again later", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

> Thank you for your answer, i tried different solution and it worked.
>   youtube.com/watch?v=U39RsxrWhIA

Comment: Please post your source code here directly instead of a link.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, `toll_bar.xml` is unnecessary.

**First**, in `activity_main.xml`, please change

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/toll_bar" />
```

to

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>
```

**Second**, create a menu file named `toolbar.xml` place it into `res/menu` directory.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_about"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:title="about"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_share"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/share"
        android:title="share"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_rate"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/rate"
        android:title="rate us"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

**Third**, here is the new `MainActivity.java`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Toolbar toolbar;


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://beta.html5test.com/");
        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/Html36289/index.html");
        // Force links and redirects to open in the WebView instead of in a browser
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        // Stop local links and redirects from opening in browser instead of WebView
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient());

        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    }

    private boolean isActivityStarted(Intent aIntent) {
        try {
            startActivity(aIntent);
            return true;
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void onClickRateThisApp() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.supercell.hayday"));
        if (!isActivityStarted(intent)) {
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.package.name"));
            if (!isActivityStarted(intent)) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Could not open Android market, please check if the market app installed or not. Try again later", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.toolbar, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_about:
                //click the about button
                break;
            case R.id.menu_share:
                //click the share button
                break;
            case R.id.menu_rate:
                onClickRateThisApp();// param view is unnecessary
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

I hope that will help you. If so, please adopt my answer.:-D Have a nice day.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i tried different solution and it worked.     
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U39RsxrWhIA

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code this would help you.

```
 Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                share.setType("text/plain");
                share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);

                                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, ""));
```

This will open the multiple sharing option of app.
This help me to share with another one .